# Dependency problems in Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apt, debian-stretch

I have a pretty fresh installation of **Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)**. 
I have installed python3.7.2 and some python-packages.
After attempting to install spyder3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-spyder`, I keep getting error messages whenever I attempt to install or remove packages.

For instance, running `sudo apt-get install unixodbc` give the following output:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc is already the newest version (2.3.4-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
12 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python-wrapt (1.9.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-wrapt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-isort (4.2.5+ds1-2+deb9u1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-isort (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-lazy-object-proxy (1.2.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lazy-object-proxy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pylint:
 pylint depends on python-isort; however:
  Package python-isort is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pylint (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-backports.functools-lru-cache (1.3-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-backports.functools-lru-cache (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pyflakes (1.3.0-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pyflakes (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-spyder:
 python3-spyder depends on pylint; however:
  Package pylint is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-spyder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-astroid:
 python-astroid depends on python-lazy-object-proxy; however:
  Package python-lazy-object-proxy is not configured yet.
 python-astroid depends on python-wrapt; however:
  Package python-wrapt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-astroid (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-sip (4.18.1+dfsg-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-sip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyqt5:
 python-pyqt5 depends on sip-api-11.3; however:
  Package sip-api-11.3 is not installed.
  Package python-sip which provides sip-api-11.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyqt5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pyflakes:
 pyflakes depends on python-pyflakes (>= 1.0.0-2); however:
  Package python-pyflakes is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pyflakes (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pyqt5.qtwebkit:
 python-pyqt5.qtwebkit depends on python-pyqt5 (= 5.7+dfsg-5); however:
  Package python-pyqt5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pyqt5.qtwebkit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-wrapt
 python-isort
 python-lazy-object-proxy
 pylint
 python-backports.functools-lru-cache
 python-pyflakes
 python3-spyder
 python-astroid
 python-sip
 python-pyqt5
 pyflakes
 python-pyqt5.qtwebkit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is basically the same output I get when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, also.

I have tried every method described at [this post](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) and [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252777/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency), but none of them fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. 
I had set python3.7.2 as my default python executable using

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.7 1
```

This is the source of my problems. 
To fix it, I reset it to python2.7.

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove python /usr/local/bin/python3.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

Then I could do

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```